# Big O Notation for string matching algo

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, big-o

What would the big O notation of the function foo be?

```
int foo(char *s1, char *s2)
{
   int c=0, s, p, found;
   for (s=0; s1[s] != '\0'; s++)
   {
      for (p=0, found=0; s2[p] != '\0'; p++)
      {
         if (s2[p] == s1[s])
         {
            found = 1;
            break;
         }
      }
      if (!found) c++;
   }
   return c;
}
```

What is the efficiency of the function foo?

a) O(n!)

b) O(n^2)

c) O(n lg(base2) n )

d) O(n)

I would have said O(MN)...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is `O(n²)` where n = max(length(s1),length(s2)) (which can be determined in less than quadratic time - see below). Let's take a look at a textbook definition:

> f(n) ∈ O(g(n)) if a positive real number c and positive integer N exist such that f(n) <= c g(n) for all n >= N

By this definition we see that n represents a number - in this case that number is the length of the string passed in. However, there is an apparent discrepancy, since this definition provides only for a single variable function `f(n)` and here we clearly pass in 2 strings with independent lengths. So we search for a multivariable definition for Big O. However, as demonstrated by Howell in ["On Asymptotic Notation with Multiple Variables"](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CCUQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fciteseerx.ist.psu.edu%2Fviewdoc%2Fdownload%3Fdoi%3D10.1.1.110.3078%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf&rct=j&q=big%20o%20multivariable&ei=NtD6Tbn6Fa-v0AHBrOmsAw&usg=AFQjCNHO5zhRuDDD4nEdyHByAodgOU-xcg&cad=rja):

> "it is impossible to define big-O notation for multi-variable functions in a way that implies all of these [commonly-assumed] properties."

There is actually a formal definition for [Big O with multiple variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiple_variables) however this requires extra constraints beyond single variable Big O be met, and is beyond the scope of most (if not all) algorithms courses. For typical algorithm analysis we can effectively reduce our function to a single variable by bounding all variables to a limiting variable `n`. In this case the variables (specifically, length(s1) and length(s2)) are clearly independent, but it is possible to bound them:

**Method 1**

```
Let x1 = length(s1)
Let x2 = length(s2)
```

The worst case scenario for this function occurs when there are no matches, therefore we perform x1 * x2 iterations.

Because multiplication is commutative, the worst case scenario foo(s1,s2) == the worst case scenario of foo(s2,s1). We can therefore assume, without loss of generality, that x1 >= x2. (This is because, if x1 < x2 we could get the same result by passing the arguments in the reverse order).

**Method 2** (in case you don't like the first method)

For the worst case scenario (in which s1 and s2 contain no common characters), we can determine length(s1) and length(s2) prior to iterating through the loops (in .NET and Java, determining the length of a string is O(1) - but in this case it is O(n)), assigning the greater to x1 and the lesser to x2. Here it is clear that x1 >= x2.

For this scenario, we will see that the extra calculations to determine x1 and x2 make this O(n² + 2n) We use the following simplification rule [which can be found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Example) to simplify to O(n²):

> If f(x) is a sum of several terms, the one with the largest growth rate is kept, and all others omitted.

**Conclusion**

for `n = x1` (our limiting variable), such that `x1 >= x2`, the worst case scenario is `x1 = x2`.
Therefore:  `f(x1) ∈ O(n²)`

**Extra Hint**

For all [homework problems posted to SO related to Big O notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/homework+big-o), if the answer is not one of:

```
O(1)
O(log log n)
O(log n)
O(n^c), 0<c<1
O(n)
O(n log n) = O(log n!)
O(n^2)
O(n^c)
O(c^n)
O(n!)
```

Then the question is *probably* better off being posted to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why do you think `m` and `n` are the same?  That doesn't make sense to me. Mathematically, O(mn) and O(n^2) are quite different things.

Comment: So in otherwords with big O we basically assume that s1 size (n) and s2 size (m) are both very large... therefore we have massiveNumN * massiveNumM ~ massiveNum^2...? Not sure what you mean that they are the "same"..?

Comment: @Sven,@Nightwolf - they are mathematically different but they are the same order of magnitude (which is what the variable in the `O` represents). Since `m` and `n` vary independently, and they represent the length of a string, iterating over them is linear. Big O notation doesn't distinguish between the actual values - just the order of magnitude.

Comment: @NightWolf: It doesn't really make sense to me -- see my answer. @Ethan:  The least you would need to do is explain what `n` actually denotes in your answer, otherwise `O(n^2)` is meaningless.

Comment: @Sven, um - seems obvious to me that by `m` and `n` we mean it be be the lengths of the strings `s1` and `s2`.

Comment: @Ethan: Agreed.  And by the `n` in `O(n^2)`? If you choose `n` to be the length of any one of the strings, the algorithm isn't `O(n^2)`.  You would need to choose `n` to be the length of the longer of the two strings.

Comment: Thanks for the link Ethan! Really help clear things up, I think this is a poorly put question, really should be O(MN) as previously stated.

Comment: @Ethan: Did you notice that the reference you gave actually states that the nested loops have complexity `O(m n)`?

Answer (score 5):

In big-O notation, we always have to define what the occuring variables mean.  `O(n)` doesn't mean anything unless we define what `n` is.  Often, we can omit this information because it is clear from context.  For example if we say that some sorting algorithm is `O(n log(n))`, `n` always denotes the number of items to sort, so we don't have to always state this.

Another important thing about big-O notation is that it only gives an upper limit -- every algorithm in `O(n)` is also in `O(n^2)`.  The notation is often used as meaning "the algorithm has the exact asymptotic complexity given by the expression (up to a constant factor)", but it's actual definition is "the complexity of the alogrithm is bounded by the given expression (up to a constant factor)".

In the example you gave, you took `m` and `n` to be the respective lengths of the two strings.  With this definition, the algorithm is indeed `O(m n)`.  If we define `n` to be the length of the longer of the two strings though, we can also write this as `O(n^2)` -- this is also an upper limit for the complexity of the algorithm.  And with the same definition of `n`, the algorithm is also `O(n!)`, but not `O(n)` or `O(n log(n))`.

Comment: Yeah its a bit confusing... Poorly worded question me thinks.. IMO O(MN) is best... 0
I would have said that if the longer string was N then it would simply be O(N) assuming M is small it becomes insignificant as N grows..? Hence we really need to understand the inputs... Guess the safest answer would be O(N^2)...

Comment: @NightWolf: `O(m n)` is the only expression that describes the exact asymptotic behavior.  It captures that the algorithm actually is `O(n)` if we keep the length of one of the strings fixed.  But without keeping one of them fixed, the tightest bound using only the maximal length `n` we can give is `O(n^2)` -- after all, it's still possible that the two strings have the same length.

Comment: @NightWolf: And it's a poorly worded question -- agreed.  (Note that I'm a mathematician and hence a bit more strict about mathematical definitions than the typical computer scientist.)

Comment: The answer is certainly not O(n!). Big O measures the limiting behavior of the function as the argument(s) (in this case the lengths of s1 and s2) approach infinity. You cannot make any assumptions about which string is larger or smaller (not that it matters). See: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html#application item 4.

Comment: @Ethan: The big-O notation only defines an upper bound -- just have a look at its definition [(1)](http://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/bigOnotation.html) [(2)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LandauSymbols.html) [(3)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_symbol).  And `n!` certainly is an upper bound for the algorithm.  As explained in my answer, big-O notation is often used to mean "tightest upper bound", but this is in contradiction to its actual definition.  Furthermore, in the case at hand the tightest upper bound is O(m n), not O(n^2).

Comment: Yes, the definition: "the limiting behavior of the function when the argument tends towards a particular value or infinity". As the argument to O  (length(s1) and length(s2)) approach infinity, length(s1) and length(s2) have the same order of magnitude - and so have the same upper bounds. If the OP answers `O(n!)` on his homework, he will surely be marked wrong.

Comment: @Ethan:  Agreed -- `O(n!)` would most certainly be marked wrong.  (Note that just because two numbers approach infinity, this doesn't mean they have the same order of magnitude.)

Comment: @Sven - they have the same order of magnitude because they are both LINEAR.

Comment: @NightWolf, if this is for a class, your professor will want to make sure that you realize that `M` and `N` both represent linear arguments to O, and that `O(M N)` =`O(N^2)`. Whether or not this is passes muster with a mathemetician, it is a commonly worded question for a class in algorithms or data structures.

Comment: Ethan: Please read the references I gave, or even the one you gave yourself.  I know I might be a bit too rigorous about the definitions given that this is a programming forum, but I just thought this one is a bit too far off.

Comment: Thanks for the help Sven & Ethan.

Answer (score 2):

**O(n^2)**

The relevant part of the function, in terms of complexity, is the nested loops.  The maximum number of iterations is the length of s1 times the length of s2, both of which are linear factors, so the worst-case computing time is O(n^2), i.e. the square of a linear factor.  As Ethan said, O(mn) and O(n^2) are effectively the same thing.

Comment: So in otherwords with big O we basically assume that s1 size (n) and s2 size (m) are both very large... therefore we have massiveNumN * massiveNumM ~ massiveNum^2...?

Comment: It's just that big O ignores the actual numbers and only cares about the class of function (i.e. order of magnitude).  So because mn and n^2 are both the product of two linear factors, they are the same in the eyes of big O.  In other words, it's because they affect the computing time in the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way:

There are two inputs.  If the function simply returned, then it's performance is unrelated to the arguments.  This would be O(1).

If the function looped over one string, then the performance is linearly related to the length of that string.    Therefore O(N).

But the function has a loop within a loop.  The performance is related to the length of s1 and the length of S2.  Multiply those lengths together and you get the number of loop iterations.  It's not linear any more, it follows a curve.  This is O(N^2).